# how to get images from "google images" using custom search API, control panel only allows to enter website names to search?

Tags: javascript, json, google-api, google-custom-search, google-image-search

I am trying to use the google custom search API to get images however I am unable to get results which are shown in google images. If I go to the custom search control panel, it says to add websites where I want to search, however I want results which are displayed in google images.

Here is the query which I am using:

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=car&searchType=image&key={my_key}&cx={my_cs}

I even tried using images.google.com as the site to search, however the results I get are very different from google images. I am looking for help on how to use custom search API to get results from google images.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out in some time, there is an option in the custom search engine box where you can set the option to search the entire web, after that everything seems to work as expected.